# Why does Script Evaluation take so long?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm using gatsbyjs and tried to optimize my webpage ([https://www.rün.run](https://www.r%C3%BCn.run)) as much as possible. Running PageSpeed gives me some decent results. What I'm wondering is, why Script Evaluation is taking so long? My js bundle size is only 257 kb (gzipped) large.

It looks like the react hydration is taking the time. So is it because of react? Or has my DOM tree to many elements?

Direct link to PageSpeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xn--rn-xka.run%2FKalista%2Fadc&tab=mobile

My goal is also to get only mobile a value of 100. How can I improve any further?

Comment: In my local it seems this one is taking longer: `webpack:///./node_modules/@mikaelkristiansson/domready/ready.js` and on that note, why are you even passing webpack sourcemap in production builds? Take it off and match things shed off your total time to load. Just so you know, you can use Audit in dev tools of chrome and then click Run audit and once done you can click Trace which will take you to performance tab in which look for Bottom-up tab at the lower left corner

Comment: gatsbyjs creates the builds. sourcemaps are activated per default. What I'm wondering as well is, why my first byte takes so long (https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190525_XN_cf3fd4f0706a8ef51c4b433502f7c699/)? The response for the first requests is saying: "x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront". Does this mean cloudfront is fetching the data always from s3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that [rehydrate](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/glossary#hydration) takes this time. I have tried it with simple component which contains just a text, and still, there is some (quite long for that case) time for main-thread work & JavaScript execution time.
And the same thing if you will test https://store.gatsbyjs.org/

But anyway, even due to this issue results with gatsby really great